# Alert notification in android group chat app

Tags: android-notifications

I am building an android group chat application which is using Firebase real time database and, i want to add an alert notification in it, so that when any user that installs the app would be able to receive notification in his or her android phone when ever any other user sends chat messages.

I would be very much glad if any one can help me out on this issue. Thanks in advance.